# Is there a way to make a component re-render only on certain state changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the two reducers, which I believe will make my component re-render when an action is dispatched from either of them:

```
    const [toDoListState, toDoListDispatch] = useReducer(toDoListReducer, []);
    const [httpState, httpDispatch] = useReducer(httpReducer, {isLoading: false, errorMsg: null});
```

The thing is, the httpState changes make the component re-renders pointlessly. Is there a way to make my component re-render only when the toDoListState changes?

From what I know, there is shouldComponentUpdate in class-based React component. What is the equivalent with ReactHooks?

I Googled and people say React.memo, but I can't seem to understand how it works and how to apply it to my code.

Comment: Why does this component need `httpState`? Can you refactor so that it isn't required here?

Answer (score 1):

The way that I'd do it is to first use something like the react profiller to see what's exactly making the component to re render. Now that I know the reason, I'd use some techniques like memo, or useMemo or callback to stop the useless re Rendering

Answer (score 1):

`useMemo` will always return the same value until dependencies change. for example

```
const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => computeExpensiveValue(a, b), [a, b]);
```

now let's say `computeExpensiveValue(1,1) === 2`

means that `memoizedValue` will now always return 2 without performing the calculations until a or b changes changes.

but the real question is: why you need http state if you don't want it to update the component?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should break your component off into two separate components. This will separate the logic.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const handleToDoListChange = () => {  }
  const handleHttpStateChange= () => {  }

  return (<>
    <ToDoList onChange={handleToDoListChange}/>
    <HttpState onChange={handleHttpStateChange}/>
  </>)
}

const ToDoList = () => {
  const [toDoListState, toDoListDispatch] = useReducer(toDoListReducer, []);

  //...
}

const HttpState = () => {
  const [httpState, httpDispatch] = useReducer(httpReducer, {isLoading: false, errorMsg: null});

  //...
}
```